# Setting global variable in grails

Tags: grails

I have a text field in gsp which is in main.gsp and the field should always be populated with a simple database query which returns one value.

I want to set it globally irrespctive of page access.

It should be set for a user session.  How can I set the value of that field globally.

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Can not we use bootstrap.grrovy for global variable declaration.If yes,how to implement. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`<g:set>`](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/set.html) with `session` scope.

```
<g:set var="foo" value="bar" scope="session" />
```

If you are looking for db access, a better implementation would be to set a service as a variable and call a method on the service bean which would make the db call:

```
<g:set var="someService" bean="someService"/>
<g:set var="foo" value="${someService.makeDBCall()}" scope="session" />
```

In either case, having a call to persistence layer from gsp is not encouraged. You can try `filters` and set the value in session.

Comment: Hi Debasis, my field is like ..                          <g:textField  size="17" style="background-color: #F5F5F5; vertical-align: bottom;"  scope="session" name="objRemTxtBox" id="objRemTxtBoxId" title="" readonly="true"/>.How to implement ur solution on this field.Please help

Answer (score 0):

You can set variable globally using ServletContext in grails controller as

```
def mySetting = servletContext["mySetting"]

servletContext["mySetting"] = "foo"
```

and then you can access on any gsp as

```
<g:set var="someName" value="${application["mySetting"]}"/>
```

and now you can use `someName` as regular variable.

Comment: Hi Abdullah, while implemeting your solution in controller,error is 
URI
    /viewer/node/type
Class
    java.lang.NullPointerException
Message
    Cannot get property 'servletContext' on null object.

Comment: Have you injected `servletContext` in controller??